# Redirect to home page after login php

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication

I've created a login-form. How can I make so that when a user logs in he/she redirects to a page where it displays his/her name? I've walked through many tutorials on how to do this, but nothing was pretty good...

main_login.php:

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

login_success.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:http://main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

checklogin.php:

```
<?php

$host="host"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="database"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799); you can use instead either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: At least you have been reading a tutorial which tells you to escape the data used in queries. The bad thing is it didn't tell you to use `PDO` or `mysqli` with prepared statements. Neither did it tell you to never **ever** store plaintext passwords in the database. And no I don't blame you, only the shitload of bad resources (/ tutorials) on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should help you a bit, but I recommend using mysqli and its a really bad idea to store your passwords in plain text. You should consider looking up mysqli, hashing passwords, and start familiarizing yourself with php 5.4 since many of the functions used here HAVE changed and are no longer supported.

checklogin.php

```
<?php

$host="host"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="database"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// Remove Magic Quotes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
  $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
  $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
}
$sql = sprintf(
  "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='%s' and password='%s' LIMIT 1;",
  mysql_real_escape_string($myusername),
  mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword)
);
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// MySQL count
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count){
  $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername; // $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true or false would work too
  $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword; // Why store the password in session data?
  header("Location: login_success.php");
}else{
  header("Location: main_login.php?msg=Login_Failed");
}
?>
```

login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username']){
  header("Location: mail_login.php");
}

?>
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

main_login.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['msg']) && !empty($_GET['msg']) echo $_GET['msg'];
?>
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Use at your own risk. :)

Comment: Thanks! But when I try to login it just shows an error that says: Server error. An error occurred when the site was getting http://mywebsite.com/main_login.php?msg=Login_Failed. It may be down for maintenance or be configured incorrectly.

Comment: Its hard to debug based on that info. I suggest checking your php error logs. (You have error logging enabled, don't you? :) Also the redirect used assumes the files are in the root folder, if they are not then you need to add the proper path to the redirect location. Its also possible your server is having trouble understanding the GET argument that I passed, although this _shouldn't_ be an issue. Try removing ?msg=Login_Failed and see what happens.

Comment: When I removed ?msg=Login_Failed and tried to log in it just took me to the www.mywebsite.com/checklogin.php with a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

To issue an HTTP redirect, the `Location` header should be properly capitalised and contain whitespace between the header name and its value:

```
header('Location: login_success.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you already have been able to redirect the user to a page if login is successfull.  You just need to add some code to that page something like echo $_SESSION['username']; hope it helps.