# login and redirect to webpage

Tags: php, html

I have a website a part of which should be blocked with a login
I used a login form which can be found everywhere on the web (see [Redirect to home page after login php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936401/redirect-to-home-page-after-login-php))

I've updated some elements (using $_SESSION and so)

so my login page is index.html

I've put

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['username'] = $username){
header("location:index.html");
}
?>
```

at the beginning of the login_success.php file
from this file you can access all other pages of the website.

My question is now:

do I have to put the "session_start () and so on" at the beginning of every page of my website

and does every page have to have .php instead of .htm?

(I tried to keep .htm but than the pages are still accessible without login if you know the name of the page)

If you know a better script for a login protection of a website, please let me know, preferably in php.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yip, you need to have it in every page.

Every page need to be .php.

A common approach is to have some 'config.php' which will have the session_start(); and other config/common stuff.

So a page will look like:

```
<?php

include('config.php');

?>
```

In general it's cleaner to have all as .php, and changing the extensions of your html files will not affect anything much. and will allow you to introduce you're php to other pages as needed.

Answer (score 1):

**yes**  you have to put the **"session_start ()** and so on" at the beginning of every page of your website

**yes** every page have to have .php extension

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to put that code in every page. You may put it in a file and include it in every other files which requires login.

Your all pages are accessible because you have wrong code in if condition part. You are not *comparing* but *assigning* value to your session variable.

Use following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username'] != $username){
header("location:index.html");
}
?>
```

Just for precaution, Remember, it must not *echo* any output before header()

Answer (score 0):

put this script:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username'] != $username){
header("location:/index.php");
die("you should be login")
}
?>
```

inside a php file called **check.php**

and add this in each page that aren't public :

```
<?php
include_once("check.php");
?>
<html>
.....
```

Comment: The webpage will still be sent, and a browser can ignore the 302.  Perhaps add a `die` in there somewhere?

Comment: You sure this `if(!$_SESSION['username'] = $username){` is correct?

Comment: @shadyyx sorry i didn't see it

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

- Set a cookie when user logs in.
- Every php file generating html should have a function check_login or something like that for checking if user is already logged in - If he is, generate page, if not redirect to login page.

To redirect to other page you can use `<? header("location: http://.........."); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to use some framework that uses one single index.php (or startup.php, etc) to handle the pages requests. Then You will have to `start_session()` and `check_login()` only once within this `index.php` before the page request is handled...